# Onclick button is working only in first list

Tags: javascript, onclick, duplicates

I want to duplicate list item with all its child elements, here is the my sample code. only in first list, on click is working, duplicated list's button is not working

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".btnMe").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var myDiv = document.querySelector(".list");
    var divClone = myDiv.cloneNode(true);
    document.querySelector('#lists').appendChild(divClone);
  })
})
```

```html
<ul id="lists">
  <li class="list">
    <p>Test</p>
    <button class="btnMe">Click Me</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of dealing with binding events, use event delegation.

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector("#lists")
wrapper.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  var btnClicked = evt.target.closest("button.btnMe");
  if (btnClicked) {
    var myDiv = document.querySelector(".list");
    var divClone = myDiv.cloneNode(true);
    wrapper.appendChild(divClone);
  }
})
```

```html
<ul id="lists">
  <li class="list">
    <p>Test</p>
    <button class="btnMe">Click Me</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

`cloneNode` copies all of the node's attributes and values but not their event listeners added using `addEventListener()`. So you need to add these event listeners again.

Your `document.querySelectorAll()` runs only the first time you load the page so a simple `document.querySelector()` should work and in that case you don't even need the `forEach()` method.

If I understand correctly, you want to clone the element the button you clicked is in. If the `button` is the child of the `li`, then you can clone [`node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode). After you cloned it, you can add the event listener function to it.

```js
function cloneParent() {
    let clone = this.parentNode.cloneNode(true);

    clone.querySelector('.btnMe').addEventListener('click', cloneParent);
    document.querySelector('#lists').appendChild(clone);
}    

document.querySelector('.btnMe').addEventListener('click', cloneParent);
```

```html
<ul id="lists">
  <li class="list">
    <p>Test</p>
    <button class="btnMe">Click Me</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Adding only one event listener and using event delegation, as @epascarello described, should be the preferred way.